# connect remote SQL server to local system

Tags: sql-server

actually i am looking for connecting SQL server database to connect to local system to get backup of database.

i have following information

server ip, user name, password, database name

may be any software to connect that...

Thanks

Comment: Do you have SQL Server Management Studio installed?

Comment: To restore a backup from your local machine to a remote machine, that machine would need to be running SQL Server under an account with sufficient credentials (and network access) to access a share on your machine. Is that the case? If not, you need to transfer the backup file to somewhere local to the SQL Server, or at least accessible to its service account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The software you will need is SQL Server Management studio :)

Comment: You don't necessarily need SQL Server Management Studio installed.  Sure it makes it easier, but if SQL Server is installed, then you can use the command line.

Comment: @air - If you do/can install SQL server management studio, then that is the easiest you will get to connect to any sql DB in your network.